Linear-array diffraction beam splitter
This question is composed of two parts. The first is about the grating equation. The second is about a particular software used for diffraction gratings.
The grating equation is
$$
\sin(\theta_m) = \frac{m \lambda}{d}.
$$
Given a fixed $\lambda$, let's say we want to split a beam into $n$ beams. If my understanding is correct, this equivalent to saying we need to choose $d$ such that there are $n$ real solutions for $\theta_m$, all other solutions being evanescent fields. So, a 1D grating with spacing $d$ would produce these $n$ beams?
I know this is a simple question, but I want to make sure that my intuition is correct because when I try to implement this using a software called GDCalc, I am not getting the expected results. GDCalc is a free software written in Matlab that is used to create binary diffraction gratings. You can find it on CodeOcean. Specifically, the download file comes with a beam splitter example (Demo17) which I am trying to modify to split into several beams. I know it is a lot to ask for someone to familiarize themselves with this software to help me, so I am not expecting anyone to do so. But, it would be greatly appreciated if you did.

Figured it out. The GDCalc example uses a Gaussian beam as the incident field. In order to see the correct number of diffracted beams, the waist of the Gaussian beam needs to be increased from the default setting. This makes sense, since a small beam would not 'see' an infinite grating, whereas a larger beam more closely approximates an plane wave, from which the standard grating equation is derived.
